# Android Room - Column conflict on entities that extend a class

Tags: database, entity, android-room

I have a `Patient` entity which extends a base `Resource` object. Now `Resource` contains a `uuid` and a `display`, which I also want to include to the patients table, so I annotate like so:

```
public class Resource implements Serializable {

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String uuid;

    @ColumnInfo
    protected String display;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And in my `Patient` entity, there are nested objects and they also extend from `Resource` (e.g. a `PatientIdentifier` and a `Person` object is embedded and has their own uuid and display):

```
@Entity(tableName = "patients")
public class Patient extends Resource implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;

    // ...

    @Embedded
    private PatientIdentifier identifier;

    @Embedded
    private Person person;

    // other variables
}
```

this results in a column name conflict - as there is a "uuid" column for a Patient, the PatientIdentifier and the Person.

I want to rename the nested objects' uuid columns after their name (e.g. "person_uuid"), similar to the `@ForeignKey` annotation in entity relationships, so may I know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the column name like that :

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "person_uuid")
```